# API url when frontend and backend are on the same machine

Tags: reactjs, iis, localhost

I have reactjs working in IIS on a windows 10 enterprise machine working as our server (don't ask!).

I haven't been successful in setting up asp.net core 6 web api with IIS but it works in the cmd line (thats another question).

The problem is the reactjs .env file contains the localhost:5000 for the default dotnet .dll running in the cmd line.

Site works when I remote into "server" and run the website. When I try to connect to the website from outside the server (over the internet) I use 'http:IP_ADDRESS:9000' and get the web page but when I perform functions for an API call, I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

How can I set .env to use the local running of dotnet without it trying to connect to the localhost of the client browser. I tried setting the .env to 0.0.0.0 or the IP address of the machine but still nothing.

Thanks

Comment: You have to resolve other questions first, and know what's the ultimate URL for your ASP.NET Core Web API. Without that, no one can tell you what URL can be used on React side. "I tried setting the .env to 0.0.0.0 or the IP address of the machine but still nothing" is expected, if ASP.NET Core Web API isn't running there properly. Windows 10 has client connection limit, so it is impossible to use it as a "server", anyway you like it or not.

Comment: What do you mean ultimate URL? Do I set this in IIS?